# JQGrid: Sorting Alphabetically on address field

Tags: javascript, sorting, jqgrid

I need my grid to sort address fields in alphabetical order. How can I achieve this via javascript on the client or php on the server? 
Right now when I click on the address header it does not sort properly (ORDERLY). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Its easy, you need to set proper formatter options for this column, which depends on what kind of data you got there.

There is wiki abouth this :
[Predefined Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter)

In case you got any problems with it, just post example of address field.

Comment: how about an example piece of code, not just a link